# Is a Shimano Ultegra FC-R8000 Crankset Compatible with a Shimano 105 5700 10-speed Groupset?

Tags: shimano, crankset, compatibility, power, groupsets

I have a 2012(?) Bianchi Via Nirone 7 with the following components:

- *Cassette*: Shimano 105, CS-5700, 11-28, 10-speed
- *Crankset*: FSA Tempo, CK-C200-3, 50/34, 172.5mm
- *Rear Derailleur*: Shimano 105, RD-5700
- *Front Derailleur*: Shimano 105, FD-5700
- *Shifters*: Shimano Tiagra
- *Chain*: SRAM PC1031, 10-speed

I'm considering upgrading the crankset (Shimano Ultegra, FC-R8000, 52/36, 175mm, to be purchased used), so that I can add a left-side crank power meter (Ultegra/Stages, to be purchased used). Given my current setup, is this upgrade possible (or advisable)? I realize this will require a new BB as the current FSA crankset is JIS. A local bike mechanic advised me that the frame is compatible with Shimano BBs.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I can provide pics if necessary, let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it may, with the following additions - pay particular attention to the front derailleur bullet:

- New BB to work with the FC-R8000 crankset (you already mentioned this)
- New front derailleur to work with the narrower spacing between the chainrings on the FC-R8000 (it is 0.4 mm narrower than the earlier 11-speed offerings, e.g., FC-R6800). The matching 8000-series FD is the FD-R8000. With your current setup, however, this would not work because your shifters are not compatible with an 11-speed FD. A cheaper option would be to try and see if your current front shifter and front derailleur can be adjusted to work with the new crankset. Also, see the information and the link following the bullet list. There is more information there. There is a question here on this exchange that addressed the use of an 11-speed crankset on a 10-speed FD equipped bike: [Shimano 105 crankset](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/68505/shimano-105-crankset)
- Probably an 11-speed chain. Usually a one-speed difference can be tolerated, which is why this bullet is prefaced with "probably," but an 11 speed chain will work just fine with the 10-speed rear derailleur and cassette.

The front derailleur/shifter is the question mark. You may be able to use your current FD with the new crankset by adjusting the limit screws to prevent the chain from jumping off the small chainring.

In addition, although [Shimano's compatibility chart](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-453&acid=C-455) does not show an 11-speed FD compatibility with your front shifter, another article does indicate that Shimano Tiagra 4700 10-speed road shifters are an exception to what the the compatibility chart indicates. If your Tiagra shifters are 4700 series, definitely worth a second look.

HOWEVER, if your Tiagra shifters work well with your REAR derailleur (5700), they are likely NOT 4700 Series Tiagra, since 4700's don't match up with them, and the same goes for your FD (FD-5700), the Tiagra 4700 shifters only match up with the FD-4700. So you are probably out of luck using an 11-speed FD with your current shifters. You most likely have the 4600 series Tiagra shifters, not the 4700. You are relegated to seeing if your current FD-5700 and Tiagra shifters can be adjusted to work with the new crankset.

**Item 8 in the link** provided below states: "Exception to this rule are Shimano 11 speed road FDs. They will not work very well with anything but Shimano 11 speed road shifters **and Shimano Tiagra 4700 10 speed road shifters**. Same goes for Tiagra 4700 FDs."

[Compatibility Front Derailleurs](https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1297/bicycle-front-derailleur-compatibility/)

Comment: 1. Thank you for the quick answer! 2. Noted on the Tiagra compatibility. Is the compatibility table you refer to the one found at productinfo.shimano.com? I had no idea that existed, so thank you for that! 3. In your opinion, is this Tiagra issue something that's 'worth a try', possibly a problem that could be 'tuned' away or adjusted around? Basically, my goal is to install a power meter on this bike as economically as possible. If I can install a used crank meter for less than a used power pedal, i'll do that. So far i've struck out in finding used power pedals for a reasonable price..

Comment: YW, I added some more information, and a link.  I will also add a link to Shimano's compatibility table.

Comment: @vkaczkowski - note the updated information I just added. You likely DO NOT have compatible Tiagra shifters for the 11-speed front derailleur. You may have success using your current shifters and FD with some adjustments, but I have not attempted that.

Comment: *try and see if your current front shifter and front derailleur*  If it does seem to work, I'd add a chain catcher if there isn't one already.  I'd suspect the 10-speed FD/shifter combination has a larger throw than the 11-speed chainring spacing, making it more likely to drop the chain inside or outside the crankset.  Assuming that's the case, I'd add a chain catcher and adjust the FD so it wouldn't dump the chain *outside* the crankset and let the chain catcher handle the inside.

Comment: I’m going to try the Ultegra crank with existing FD and shifters. Will report back with results in a week or two. Many thanks!

Comment: Update: Swapped the FSA crank for the Ultegra FC-R8000. Works great! No issues or dropped chains through an easy Z2 ride and an FTP test on a trainer. The shop installed a Shimano BB-RS500, 68mm. Slight adjustments to the FD-5700 to accommodate new chainring spacing (wish I knew what, exactly, but sadly I didn't have a chance to talk with the mechanic that did the work). Still using the original Tiagra 4600 shifters. Thanks again for the insight and suggestions!!!